# Unexpected value 'CeiboShare' in Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular

I am using angular4 and I have used `ng2-social-share` to use social share buttons, it is working fine but when I publish my project it is throwing me below error:-

> ERROR in Unexpected value 'CeiboShare in
>   E:/code/SportsFoundation/Gamification.Clients.Spa/node_modules/ng2-social-share/src/ng2-social-share.d.ts'
>   declared by the module 'AppModuleShared in
>   E:/code/SportsFoundation/Gamification.Clients.Spa/ClientApp/app/app.module.shared.ts'.
>   Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

I am following below article:-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-social-share

In Angular 4 we do not have [directive] so I am using it in declaration part of @ngModule

Comment: The plugin need to be updated to support Angular >= 2.0
https://github.com/Epotignano/ng2-social-share/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right, problem is with package that it is not supportable during building of project for angular version greater than 2 as directives are no more part of components decorator and even if you declare it in declarations of module then your app supports package on your local but when you build up the app for production you ends up with an error.

What you could do is to remove the package and its code.

Use these functions on your typescript file and call it from the template, you will get the same output as ng2-social-share was giving.

**Providing here 5 Social Media Share** - Facebook, Pinterest, Twitter, GooglePlus, LinkedIn

```
  // Facebook share won't work if your shareUrl is localhost:port/abc, it should be genuine deployed url
  shareOnFacebook(shareUrl: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    window.open(`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${shareUrl}`, 'sharer');
  }

  shareOnPinterest(shareUrl: string, img: string, desc: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    img = encodeURIComponent(img);
    desc = encodeURIComponent(desc);
    window.open(`https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button?url=${shareUrl}&media=${img}&description=${desc}`, 'sharer');
  }

  shareOnTwitter(shareUrl: string, desc: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    desc = encodeURIComponent(desc);
    window.open(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${shareUrl}&text=${desc}`, 'sharer');
  }

  shareOnGooglePlus(shareUrl: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    window.open(`https://plus.google.com/share?url=${shareUrl}`, 'sharer');
  }

  // LinkedIn share won't work if your shareUrl is localhost:port/abc, it should be genuine deployed url
  shareOnLinkedIn(shareUrl: string, title: string, summary: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    window.open(`https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=${shareUrl}&title=${title}&summary=${summary}`, 'sharer');
  }
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else.
Thanks!